# firebase snapshot longevity

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm building an iOS app and I'm using firebase.
How long does a snapshot listener work? Does the listener work when I quit the application?
Because I don't want my application to listen to changes if it's closed.

Comment: Yes, listeners are disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase listeners stay active until you remove them, or the app process is killed.  If the app is launched again after being killed (which **will** happen eventually if the user leaves), you would need to add any listeners again.